# Array named capture using PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

If named capture matches multiple times, is it possible to retrieve all matches?

Example

```
<?php

$string = 'TextToMatch [some][random][tags] SomeMoreMatches';
$pattern = "!(TextToMatch )(?P<tags>\[.+?\])+( SomeMoreMatches)!";

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Which results in

```
Array
(
    [0] => TextToMatch [some][random][tags] SomeMoreMatches
    [1] => TextToMatch 
    [tags] => [tags]
    [2] => [tags]
    [3] =>  SomeMoreMatches
)
```

Is is possible to get something like

```
Array
(
    [0] => TextToMatch [some][random][tags] SomeMoreMatches
    [1] => TextToMatch 
    [tags] => Array
        (
            [0] => [some]
            [1] => [random]
            [2] => [tags]
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => [some]
            [1] => [random]
            [2] => [tags]
        )
    [3] =>  SomeMoreMatches
)
```

using only `preg_match`?

---

I am aware that I can explode tags, but I wonder if I can do this with preg_match (or similiar function) only.

---

Other example

```
$input = "Some text [many][more][other][tags][here] and maybe some text here?";
```

Desirable output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Some text [many][more][other][tags][here] and maybe some text here?
    [1] => Some text 
    [tags] => Array
        (
            [0] => [many]
            [1] => [more]
            [2] => [other]
            [3] => [tags]
            [4] => [here]
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => [many]
            [1] => [more]
            [2] => [other]
            [3] => [tags]
            [4] => [here]
        )
    [3] =>   and maybe some text here?
)
```

Comment: No, it is not  possible in PHP.

Comment: You need use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Comment: Please improve this question with 2 or 3 more sample inputs and your expected result so that we can see how your data varies.  I would like to provide an answer so that this page can be resolved.

Comment: @mickmackusa Current example is quite good(but I added another) data pattern is `TEXT TAGS OTHER_TEXT`. This was question asked out of curiosity so answer __NO__ which Wiktor provided is pretty much what I expected but wondered if maybe I am missing some prettier way

Comment: Do you actually need the extra named capture group?  Do you only really need the tags? or are the leading and trailing text components relevant to your project?  Does your real input ever go back to offering tags? or is it always a "tag sandwich"?  I'll code something up.

Comment: @mleko Is this usable for your project? https://3v4l.org/I0fgX  I wonder how you are using the data in this structure.

Comment: @mickmackusa @mickmackusa `Do you actually need the extra named capture group?`  - no, `are the leading and trailing text components relevant to your project?` - trailing text is relevant, leading can be discarded but must be present, `is it always a "tag sandwich"?` - yes, `Is this usable for your project? 3v4l.org/I0fgX` - yes, but I think it's even more complicated than explode version

Comment: Do the tags only have letters in them? No spaces, right? (Hard to tell with fake data)  Please edit your desired output and I'll adjust my code.

Comment: Perhaps this is refined/direct enough for your project: https://3v4l.org/RQJ5L  Any fringe cases that this doesn't accommodate?

Comment: @mickmackusa When you posted comment that you wan't to resolve this I posted answer with my current solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/50038719/3552932 I have working code, I just wondered if it can be done simpler :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as Wiktor stated([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450444/array-named-capture-using-php-regex?noredirect=1#comment85903054_49450444), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450444/array-named-capture-using-php-regex?noredirect=1#comment85920466_49450559)), it is not possible to do using only `preg_match`

Solution that *just works*

```
<?php

$string = 'TextToMatch [some][random][tags] SomeMoreMatches';
$pattern = "!(TextToMatch )(?P<tags>\[.+?\]+)( SomeMoreMatches)!";

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
$matches[2] = $matches["tags"] = array_map(function($s){return "[$s]";}, explode("][", substr($matches["tags"],1,-1)));
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and modify the reg exp:

```
preg_match_all('/(?P<tags>\[.+?\])/', $string, $matches);
```

Just remove the `+` after `)` to set one pattern and `preg_match_all` make a  global search

If you need the specific answer that you posted, try with:

```
$string = '[some][random][tags]';
$pattern = "/(?P<tags>\[.+?\])/";

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

$matches = [
  implode($matches['tags']), end($matches['tags'])
] + $matches;

print_r($matches);
```

You get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [some][random][tags]
    [1] => [tags]
    [tags] => Array
        (
            [0] => [some]
            [1] => [random]
            [2] => [tags]
        )

)
```

Comment: Your answer realized me that my minimal example is not complete :) I updated question. But +1 from me. BTW I am aware that I can explode this, but wondered if I can do this with preg_match (or similiar function) only

Comment: @mleko Did you see my comment? **No, it is not possible in PHP.**

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeap, I did saw it and there is good chance that this is the correct answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why haven't you posted this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated in your comments that you are not actually interested in the leading substring before the set of tags, and because you stated that you don't necessarily need the named capture group (I never use them), you really only need to remove the first bit, split the string on the space after the set of tags, then split each tag in the set of tags.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fbk0c))

```
$split = explode(' ', strstr($input, '['), 2);  // strstr() trims off the leading substring
var_export($split);                     // ^ tells explode to stop after making 2 elements
```

Produces:

```
array (
  0 => '[many][more][other][tags][here]',
  1 => 'and maybe some text here?',
)
```

Then the most direct/clean way to split those square bracketed tags, is to use the zero-width position between each closing bracket (`]`) and each opening bracket (`[`).  Since only regex can isolate these specific positions as delimiters, I'll suggest `preg_split()`.

```
$split[0] = preg_split('~]\K~', $split[0], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_export($split);       ^^- release/forget previously matched character(s)
```

This is the final output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '[many]',
    1 => '[more]',
    2 => '[other]',
    3 => '[tags]',
    4 => '[here]',
  ),
  1 => 'and maybe some text here?',
)
```